# boards for combining old chips in order to get a processing boost

Tags: cpu

While modern CPUs(CPUs as in just the chips, not the entire casing as is usually understood):

[chip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcutW.png)

old ones (Like the core 2 duo have low prices), so I was wondering if there was a way/motherboard that could combine several of these in some way.

**EDIT**: even though they may not be joined, is there some simpler more of a pocket sized boards, that would let me utilize the CPUs for a programmable computing power. Something that would let me make these more powerful version of raspberry pis.

Comment: A CPU is engineered with the motherboard in a unified design for best speed. I do not see how you could simply add CPUs.

Comment: What you want is not possible.  The most you could hope for is a motherboards that supported multiple Core 2 Duo, which of course, did not exist even when Core 2 Duos were the current generation.

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: A Lada engine is not as good as a modern Mercedes. Can I buy a car that I could fit for or five old Lada engines in? …No.

Comment: @John , even though they may not be joined, is there some simpler more of a pocket sized boards, that would let me utilize the CPUs for a programmable computing power. Something that would let me make these more powerful version of raspberry pis.

Comment: @Ramhound , even though they may not be joined, is there some simpler more of a pocket sized boards, that would let me utilize the CPUs for a programmable computing power. Something that would let me make these more powerful version of raspberry pis.

Comment: @BumbleBee No, there isn't. At best, a cluster of several normal boards could be tried but that would be so ridiculously energy inefficient to even theoretically consider it. You have good intentions, no doubt about that, but in this case it's wishful thinking that reality swiftly crushed down.

Comment: @BumbleBee - No; What you want does not exist.  Since no product exists for that processor you are out of luck.  Only multi-socket motherboard exist for x86 hardware, and only certain product lines, at the blessing of AMD and Intel. There are x86 solutions that are similar to RPi, they are 4x times the price, but are fully functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generalized answer:

It might be interesting to experiment using old CPU's in a Multiprocessing manner... but that is almost never feasible for general computing.

Generally, the software has to be tuned and written in a manner that supports this.
One public example: https://foldingathome.org/?lng=en-US

For interesting experiments see the videos this fellow has published on youtube:
https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/56159
... he has tried a few Raspberry Pi setups.